# Multiple File Uploads

Tags: php

I cannot upload more than 3 files with

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple/>
```

Displays Array Empty on var_dump, but when there are 3 or less it displays each file properly.

Comment: You're going to need to give us more then this to go on

Comment: Probably you are exceeding [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) or `upload_max_filesize` (maybe).

Comment: Thanks Michael, all resolved changed max_size in ini

Comment: Not an answer but you should correct typo: `name="file[] multiple` to `name="file[]" multiple`

Comment: can u please post your code ?

Comment: @DevangRathod: There is no significant code to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Check your js and php-code. According to specification, you can set the value of count of uploaded files in js at the front-end and php at the back-end. It looks like, your array is at the server php-script filters.